# How do I write a list with decimals?

Tags: python

I need to be able to write a list with decimals. I'm supposed to use a split as well. Can I combine split and f-string somehow? or do i have to write it separately.

```
list =[]
while True:
  number= input()
  print(number.split(':'))
  print(f'{number:.2f}')
```

```
list =[]
while True:
  number= input()
  print(f'(number.split(':')){number:.2f}')
```

Neither of these codes work. I just wanted to show my working progress. I appreciate all help I can get.

Edit:
I'm supposed to put in for example 5:2:4 and get an output
[5.0, 2.0, 4.0].
I'm wondering how I can get the 0 added to my list. I hope this makes more sense. I have just recently started programming.

Comment: Show an example of your input and what you hope the output will look like

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Maybe what you are supposed to do is input a string such as `4.1 5.6 7.8` use split to separate the numbers, convert each to a float decimal and store them all in Python list. If so you could code these steps.

Comment: `print(number.split('.'))?`

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
input = "5:2:4"
[float(x) for x in input.split(":")] # list comprehension
# outputs [5.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a list of integers separated by colon. The easiest way to show such values with one decimal place is to convert them to float.

This will do what you ask:

```
user_input = input('Enter some integers separated by colon: ')
user_ints = [float(n) for n in user_input.split(':')]
print(user_ints)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter some integers separated by colon: 5:2:4
[5.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list elements are strings, not numbers:

```
>>> "2:3:4".split(":")
['2', '3', '4']
```

You can convert a string that holds the valid representation of a floating-point number:

```
>>> float("2")
2.0
```

And applying that procedure to an entire list:

```
>>> [float(x) for x in "2:3:4".split(":")]
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = (input("Enter numbers seperated by a comma: ")).split(",")
b = []
for i in a:
    i = float(i)
    b.append(i)
print(b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can try this codes:

```
import random
list=[]
for i in range(1,4,1):
 l1=random.randint(1,9)
 l2=random.randint(1,9)
 list.append( str(l1)+'.'+str(l2))

print(list)
```

or

```
list2=[]
for i in range(1,4,1):
 l1=int(input('integer'))
 l2=int(input('float'))
 list2.append( str(l1)+'.'+str(l2))

print(list2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).